# Issue while transforming the json using jolt spec

Tags: jolt

I am trying to jolt transformation spec for the below input :

```
{
  "a": {
    "serviceTesta": "Testa1",
    "b": {
      "serviceTestb": "Testb1",
      "c": [
        {
          "name": "x",
          "value": "100",
          "desc": "this is description of X"
        },
        {
          "name": "y",
          "value": "200",
          "desc": "this is description of y"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

and the expected output is as below :

```
[
  {
    "Testa1_Testb1_x": "100",
    "Testa1_Testb1_x_desc": "this is description of X"
  },
  {
     "Testa1_Testb1_y": "100",
    "Testa1_Testb1_y_desc": "this is description of y"
  }
]
```

My Spec :

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "a": {
        "b": {
          "c": {
            "*": {
              "value": "@(4,serviceTesta).@(3,serviceTestb)@(1,name)"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
 }

 ]
```

I am new to jolt ,  tried different ways , but couldnt get desired output.
Any help is highly appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the desired result by doing secondary shift on your transformation:

Which uses the a combination of `*` and `&n` to build up your key.

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "a": {
        "b": {
          "c": {
            "*": {
              "value": "@(4,serviceTesta).@(3,serviceTestb).@(1,name)"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "*": {
            "@": "&3_&2_&1"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```